# Copying Array elements to Hash

Tags: perl

I have an array of Hashes with the following structure:

```
@fields 
(
 {
   "id" => "Name",
   "type" => "Text",
   "value" = undef,
 },
 {
   "id" => "DOB",
   "type" => "Date",
   "value" = undef,
 },
);
```

and I have an array with the following elements:

```
@data = ("John", "10/10/1970");
```

What wold be the best way to copy the elements of the `@data` to `@fields` to get the following without having to iterate and use array indices.

```
@fields 
(
 {
   "id" => "Name",
   "type" => "Text",
   "value" = "John",
 },
 {
   "id" => "DOB",
   "type" => "Date",
   "value" = "10/10/1970",
 },
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hash slice would have worked if this was within a single hash reference. However, since you have to populate a specific field across multiple hash references, a loop will be needed.

```
use List::Util 'min';

$fields[$_]->{value} = $data[$_] for 0 .. min( $#fields, $#data );
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you should make `@fields` into a hash instead, which would allow you to easily retrieve a field by name.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %fields =  
(
    Name => {
        type  => "Text",
        value => undef,
    },
    DOB => {
        type  => "Date",
        value => undef,
    },
);

my @data = ("John", "10/10/1970");

$fields{Name}->{value} = $data[0];
$fields{DOB}->{value} = $data[1];

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper %fields;
```